# Solidity: "The transaction has been reverted to the initial state." unable to run specific function even after changed into previous stage

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am beginner of Solidity and am trying to run a basic solidity code using Remix

Below is the code

```
stage - 1
contract Calculator{

    uint256 result =0;


    function add( uint256 num1, uint256 num2 ) public {
        result = 0;
        result = num1+num2;
    }

    function substraction2( uint256 num1, uint256 num2) public {
        
         result = 0;
         result =  num1-num2;
    }

    function multiple(uint256 num1, uint256 num2) public {
          result = 0;
          result = num1 * num2;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint256){
        return result;
    }
}
```

the above code works. however i made changes to the substract function in which i invoked add function like below

```
function substraction2(uint256 num1, uint256 num2) external {
    // Call the add function to perform addition
    add(num1, num2);

    // Perform subtraction and update the result
    result = result + (num2 - num1);
}
```

even this was also working. But after i reverted to the previous stage- (stage - 1) and deployed, i got below error

```
transact to Calculator.substraction2 errored: Error occured: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

What exact cause of error?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parenthesis in sutraction2,

```
function subtraction2(uint num1, uint num2) {
      add(num1,num2);
      // parenthesis has no effect here, 
      // But (num2 - num1) may go negative and it overflows the type uint
      result = result + num2 - num1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Abi, the above code mentioned in the question working fine, but when i reverted back to the previous code(stage1), then it start showing the error